# Pack uri in wpf

Tags: wpf, url, wpf-controls

I found in application two difference examples of Image Source URI.

What the difference between them?

```
Source="/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Images/image1.png"

Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Images/image1.png"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is short form of Pack URI, second - full. Details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx